# C - Read the array from the file and display the amount of introduced lines on the screen

Tags: c

Im trying to make a program do write to a file and read from it. The problem is when i open the file to read only and show the data in it, it does not show me all lines. If i insert a bigger number of lines it will show random input.

```
for (i = 0; i < stud2[i].k; ++i)
{
printf("Name: %s\tHeight: %d\n", stud2[i].name, stud2[i].height);
}
```

If i change the variable stud2[i].k to 100 it will show me random data input.

I tried to add the variable k to the struct so it can save how many times i run the software and then tried to add it to stud2[i].k but i cant get it working.

How can i make it only show the number of executions and not random lines of data input? Thank you

Heres the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
char name[50];
int height;
int k;
};

int main()
{
struct student stud1[100], stud2[100];
FILE *fptr;
int i, x;

printf("How many do you want to add?");
scanf("%d", &x);


fptr = fopen("study.txt", "ab+");
for (i = 0; i < x; ++i)
{

    fflush(stdin);
    stud1[i].k = stud1[i].k + x;
    printf("Enter name: ");
    gets(stud1[i].name);
    printf("Enter height: ");
    scanf("%d", &stud1[i].height);

}

fwrite(stud1, sizeof(stud1), 1, fptr);
fclose(fptr);
fptr = fopen("study.txt", "rb");
fread(stud2, sizeof(stud2), 1, fptr);
for (i = 0; i < stud2[i].k; ++i)
{
    printf("Name: %s\tHeight: %d\n", stud2[i].name, stud2[i].height);
}
fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: Please also include the contents of your `study.txt` file.

Comment: @amn the file is in binary, should i include?

Comment: `Stu1` and `Stu2` are local (stack allocated) which means: not zeroed. So, for example, `stud1[i].k = stud1[i].k + x;` will result in....garbage...... And: what is the aim of that sum?

Comment: @LPs i was trying to make a sum so it would only show the amount of times it executed.
Ex:
How many times do you want to run? 2

Next time i would run, i would say 3

So it would sum those 2 numbers and only show 5 lines of insert data

Comment: Unrelated, `fflush(stdin);` <=== stop that. `fflush` is only standard-supported on *output* streams; not input streams. There are a multitude of ways to flush out `stdin` correctly; that isn't one of them.

Comment: @carjaquim You are summin a not initialized value with itself and the `x` variable....

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for your advice. Can you tell me the correct way so i can search?